# Reinstall Aptana Studio 3 bundles to get my custom snippets back?

Tags: javascript, aptana, code-snippets, textmatebundles, bundles

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 for JavaScript development.
Day 1, I tried importing some old favorite Textmate snippets etc. with limited success.
Some keys like dot, comma, "d + number" etc. takes precedence over my custom commands and the situation has become almost unbearable ...
*(Hmm, no, unbearable situation should be reserved for this: http://www.usaid.gov/fwd/)*

What should I do next?

*I really just want to take back control :)*

1) How do I make sure my own custom snippets always takes precedence in all scopes?
2) How do I delete all existing (conflicting?) bundles and get some decent ones back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the majority of those cases were issues with 3.0.4. Can you try updating to 3.0.5 beta to see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Seems I'm already on 3.05 though. Anything else I can try? Can I delete the bundles and install them one by one? Are there some Aptana->Preferences things I can tweak? Thanks :)

Comment: The default bundles are packaged with Studio, so a little difficult to try. Can you file a ticket with the specific thing you want to do (example of snippets in a particular situation) and we can figure out the best approach?

Comment: I reinstalled Aptana and deleted all rubles. Now it's working perfectly fine!